# Why i can't ping to any address using a static ip?

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, ping, lan

We are provided with LAN inside our hostel, ip address starts from 172.**.**.**. But few of days ago we start getting ip address of something like 192.**.**.**. and internet stops working. We are told to fill static ip in setting( by seniors) in order to use internet. We did it ,internet starts working but i don't know why after that i am not able to ping anything like
wheneer i type ping 8.8.8.8 it goes into loop, there is a server inside our college with address glug.nith.ac.in whenever i try to ping that with the given name like `ping glug.nith.ac.in` it says

> ping: glug.nith.ac.in: Name or service not known

whenever i try to ping that server with its ip address like 172.**.**.__ it again goes into loop.
**SSH** too not working.
Why so ? And what's going arround with network in layman term?

Comment: It sounds as if someone brought up a second DHCP server. Or they corrupted the configuration of the primary one. Without working DHCP, not only do you need to set a static IP, you also need to set the netmask, DNS IP and default routes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ping: glug.nith.ac.in: Name or service not known

is because your DNS Server is not reachable from your system. So the website you are accessing cannot be mapped into an IP address. IP address helps you to make calls to the website servers and load the response contents. Since its not reachable, you are getting `Name or service not known` error.

> **192...**

This always is the local network IP address assigned to you when you are connected to a WIFI Router or other routers in LAN(Local Area Network). If these routers doesn't have any incoming internet connections, then they create their own subnet and your system will be a part of this subnet. You wont have access to the internet in most of the cases.

> **172...**

Now this could be your IP address allowed to access the internet according to DHCP server (the server that maintains the IP address allocations and Internet accesses). Hence you are able to access the Internet.

I tried my best to keep it simple though there are lot many concepts involved here. I would recommend you to go through `Data communications and networking by Behrouz A. Forouzanif` are interested to know more. Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thanks man. Can you tell me what i can do to make ping and ssh work.

Comment: It is more likely that your DNS servers are not set properly. Using a working connection to a DNS server you can ping any website and connect using ssh to other systems. So ensure that you have proper DNS servers connectivity to your systems. Do mark it as an answer if it helps. :)